# MVC 4 Routing with UrlParameter.Optional expects parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my MVC solution i have Different areas. One of the area's registration is class is displaied below.

```
 public class CommercialAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "Commercial";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {

            context.MapRoute(
                "Commercial_default",
                "Commercial/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new {  action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Based on this the url *hxxp://localhost:63363/Commercial/VesselManagement* should call the VesselManagement controller's Index action method. It did call as expected once in a while. But now it does not execute the action method.

But if i type the Url as *hxxp://localhost:63363/Commercial/VesselManagement/index/abc* the Action method Index is called and the parameter abs is passed.

Not only to this action method but to all action methods in the whole application the url has to be called with in this pattern. What could be the issue. Thank you all in advance for the help.

### **Note:** I have used hxxp insted of http

---

The Global.asx

```
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            //RouteDebug.RouteDebugger.RewriteRoutesForTesting(RouteTable.Routes);
            //Configure FV to use StructureMap
            var factory = new StructureMapValidatorFactory();

            //Tell MVC to use FV for validation
            ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider(factory));
            DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
        }
    }
```

---

The VesselManagement Index() Action

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {

            InitialData();
            return View();
        }
```

**NOTE:** Just now i noticed that index does not take any parameters but i know that wouldn'd effect the routing.

Comment: Can you show your other routes, such as those in the global context?  My guess is a different route is picking it up, but I can't be certain without more context.

Comment: What is the signature of `VesselManagement`? Is the `id` parameter a nullable type?

Comment: when `hxxp://localhost:63363/Commercial/VesselManagement` is called The resource could not be found.    HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I am really sorry the issue was due to a mistake by one of my colleague where he created an Area and for the area registration he has mentioned the routing rule incorrectly.

```
 public class SharedAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "Shared";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Shared_default",
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", //<---- This made the issue with routing

                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

How i figured out the mistake ill explain the steps below so that it would be helpful.

First i installed the [Route Debugger](http://nuget.org/packages/routedebugger)

Then Wrote the Application_Error in the Global.asx to handle the error. if this is not written the Route Debugger will not be able to find the routing.

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
            // Log the exception.

            //ILogger logger = Container.Resolve<ILogger>();
           // logger.Error(exception);

            Response.Clear();

            HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;

            RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");

            if (httpException == null)
            {
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index");
            }
            else //It's an Http Exception, Let's handle it.
            {
                switch (httpException.GetHttpCode())
                {
                    case 404:
                        // Page not found.
                        routeData.Values.Add("action", "HttpError404");
                        break;
                    case 500:
                        // Server error.
                        routeData.Values.Add("action", "HttpError500");
                        break;

                    // Here you can handle Views to other error codes.
                    // I choose a General error template  
                    default:
                        routeData.Values.Add("action", "General");
                        break;
                }
            }

            // Pass exception details to the target error View.
            routeData.Values.Add("error", exception);

            // Clear the error on server.
            Server.ClearError();

            // Avoid IIS7 getting in the middle
            Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

            // Call target Controller and pass the routeData.
            //IController errorController = new ErrorController();
            //errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(
            //     new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
        }
```

Then i typed the URL hxxp://localhost:63363/Commercial/VesselManagement and the output was
[image]

In the output route data and data token clearly says it tries to find the commercial controller and VesselManagement ACtion inside Shared area.

Reason for the error is Shared Area routing incorrectly specified and when that is corrected by addeing Share in frount it ws resolved.

public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Shared_default",
            "Shared/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }

Thanks to RouteDebugger

**NOTE:** Routing works top to bottom and the moment it finds a matching route it will ignore the rest.